# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate' Python

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, nlp, attributeerror

Im working on doing some NLP with textual data from doctors just trying to do some basic preprocessing text cleaning trying to remove stop words and punctuation.  I have already given the program a list of punctuations and stop words.

My text data looks something like this:

> "Cyclin-dependent kinases (CDKs) regulate a variety of fundamental cellular processes. CDK10 stands out as one of the last orphan CDKs for which no activating cyclin has been identified and no kinase activity revealed. Previous work has shown that CDK10 silencing increases ETS2 (v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene homolog 2)-driven activation of the MAPK pathway, which confers tamoxifen resistance to breast cancer cells"

Then my code looks like:

```
import string

# Create a function to remove punctuations
def remove_punctuation(sentence: str) -> str:
    return sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

# Create a function to remove stop words
def remove_stop_words(x):
    x = ' '.join([i for i in x.split(' ') if i not in stop])
return x

# Create a function to lowercase the words
def to_lower(x):
    return x.lower()
```

So then I try to apply the functions to the Text column

```
train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(remove_punctuation)
train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(remove_stop_words)
train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(lower)
```

And I get an error message like:

> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in 
> >     ----> 1 train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(remove_punctuation)
> >           2 train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(remove_stop_words)
> >           3 train['Text'] = train['Text'].apply(lower)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
>   apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3192
>   else:    3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3195     3196         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in remove_punctuation(sentence)
>         3 # Create a function to remove punctuations
>         4 def remove_punctuation(sentence: str) -> str:
>   ----> 5     return sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
>         6 
>         7 # Create a function to remove stop words
>
> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'

Why am I getting this error.  Im guessing because digits appear in the text?

Comment: The error message suggests that the `train.Text` column seems to contain float values rather than strings.

Comment: Did Seb's suggestion help?  Do you need anymore assistance?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I had suspected.  I don’t see why or how that occurred.  What is the best way to filter out float values from a Pandas DF column or convert them to strings even better?  Thanks